# Failure scenarios for ADB Adapter

Tags: adb, tibco

I want to test failure scenarios for ADB Adapter in tibco. The states are C,N,F,P.
P = indicates pending acknowledgement. 
N = indicates that a new message has arrived, but has not yet been published. 
C = indicates complete. 
F = indicates failed.

Can someone tell me in which scenario can I get status as F or P.

Comment: You're talking about the statuses in the publishing table, correct?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, C stands for "confirmed", not "complete".
The message goes into the C state after a subscriber has confirmed its reception using the activity "Confirm".
So you can obtain a P state, for instance, by turning off the subscriber process while the publisher process is producing. All the messages sent but not consumed are in "P" (and you should find them into the ledger file)

I'm sorry, I've never seen the F state :-)